# How to pull in an array to a PHP MySQL output?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to pull in this date for each part of my database, but I am missing some element to make it work and not sure what I am missing?

```
 $modified[] = array(date("m/d/y", strtotime($row[audit_modify_date]))."<br />".date("g:i a", strtotime($row[audit_modify_date])),);

//query
 for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$modified</td>";
        echo"<tr>";
 }
```

They output just says Array.

Comment: why are you using an array anyways? that looks like you're generating a single string anyways, which can go into `$modified` directly, not need to be turned into a single element array.

Comment: It gets pulled many times for multiple rows, But what would be a better way then?

Comment: doesn't matter. why have a double array in the first place? `for(...) { $modified = date(...strtotime(...)); echo " blah blah $modified "; }` no need for an array at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the array, not the elements in the array

`echo "<td>$modified</td>";`

either

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$modified[$i]."</td>";
    echo"<tr>";
}
```

or

```
foreach ($modified as $m) {
    echo $m;
}
```

**edit** actually what? I don't understand what you're doing

Comment: It still says array, and I know you are right.  Must be some other little thing

Comment: are you sure you don't mean `$modified = ...` instead of `$modified[] = ...`?

Comment: @SDJ it's because you are putting another array inside your $modified array.

Comment: I was because of the 1st modified[], should have been without the [] brackets

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using $modified[ ] = array(....), it becomes multidimensional array.
Use below code

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$modified[0][$i]</td>";
    echo"<tr>";
}
```

Or just

```
echo "<td>$modified[0][0]</td>";
```

Other thing is instead of creating a array, make it a variable like shown below

```
$modified=date("m/d/y", strtotime($row[audit_modify_date]))."<br />".date("g:i a", strtotime($row[audit_modify_date]));

//query
   for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$modified</td>";
    echo"<tr>";
 }
```

Note: use the appropriate according to your requirement.

Comment: Great idea!  This code keeps looking better.  Thanks!